# client timed out (110: Connection timed out) while waiting for request, client: x.x.x.x, server: 0.0.0.0:443

Tags: http, nginx, load-balancing, ip-address

What is the client ip here? x.x.x.x is the ip address where nginx forwards the request or this is the ip address from where nginx received request. Also, we are seeing too many of these errors in our nginx logs. Any reason why we get this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

x.x.x.x is the client address.
Nginx is listening on 443 port(one of the ports its listening on). Client timed out indicates your backend server/service where nginx is proxying the request to is not responding for some reason(the backend service could be having a exception) timing out the client request. Please check your nginx config (nginx.conf file) usually located at /etc/nginx on a linux box and locate where nginx is forwarding the request to for port 443. Once you identify this backend service you can check its logs to debug further on what the issue could be with the service.

Comment: If it was a backend service it would say upstream timed out. Here its client timed out.